# read exactly a string in the next line after maching the condition

Tags: java

I have this simple and I am trying to find the string `all` and after finding it it should jump to next line and look for the integer value `30`  and store it in Integer variable.

**Simple:**

```
spoon 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
apple 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 all 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
chair 05:11 05:41 06:14 06:44 30 07:14 07:44 08:14 17:14 17:44 18:14 18:44 19:14 19:44
table 05:13 05:43 06:17 06:47 07:17 07:47 08:17 Min 17:17 17:47 18:17 18:47 19:17 19:47
```

**Code:**

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    int lineNum = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        lineNum++;
        if(line.contains(" all ")){
            //go to the next line and find the integer value 30 then store it.
            System.out.println("I found it on line " +lineNum);



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
int lineNum = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    lineNum++;
    if(line.contains(" all ")){
        scanner.nextLine(); // this will skip to the next line
        System.out.println("I found it on line " +lineNum);
        // look for the integer value 30 and store it in Integer variable.
    }
```

Basically all you have to do is once the line contains the `all` word then you call scanner.nextLine() which will bring you to the next line and then after that you can look for `30` and then store it.  Once you're finished if there's nothing left for you to do then you can call `break;` to exit the while loop

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. Please can you give me advice how can I find this integer value since it is not always `30` it can be `15` or `20`?

Comment: You can search for `30` by using the String function `indexOf("30")` which will return where `30` is

Comment: the problem I don't know the value that I am looking for what I know it has this form  `space+Integer+space`. I have to replace Integer with something to find this value?

Comment: Then all you have to do is define variables to store what you're looking for and what you want to replace it with.  So it can look something like this: `line.replaceFirst(/*the Integer I want to replace*/, /*replacement*/);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution to find the token on the following line at the same index as the all token on the previous line.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    boolean fetchRecordFromNextLine = false;
    int fetchTokenIndex = -1;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        if (line.contains(" all ")) {
            fetchRecordFromNextLine = true;
            fetchTokenIndex = Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).indexOf("all");
            continue;
        } 
        if (fetchRecordFromNextLine && fetchTokenIndex >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Fetched token " + line.split(" ")[fetchTokenIndex]);
        }
        fetchRecordFromNextLine = false;
        fetchTokenIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is the index is different in the other case. Is there any way to fix that in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Complete, working, executable example solving given problem is here:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProgramScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString =
            "spoon 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41\n"
            + "apple 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 all 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41\n"
            + "chair 05:11 05:41 06:14 06:44 07:14 07:44 30 08:14 17:14 17:44 18:14 18:44 19:14 19:44\n"
            + "table 05:13 05:43 06:17 06:47 07:17 07:47 08:17 Min 17:17 17:47 18:17 18:47 19:17 19:47\n";

        Scanner scannerLines = new Scanner(inputString);
        for (int iLine = 0; scannerLines.hasNextLine(); ++iLine) {
            String line = scannerLines.nextLine();
            if (line.contains("all")) {
                System.out.println("found \"all\" one line index " + iLine);
                if (!scannerLines.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println("PROBLEM: no next line");
                } else {
                    String nextLine = scannerLines.nextLine();
                    Scanner scannerWordsNextLine = new Scanner(nextLine);
                    for (; scannerWordsNextLine.hasNext() && !scannerWordsNextLine.hasNextInt(); ) {
                        scannerWordsNextLine.next(); //skipping words until integer
                    }
                    if (scannerWordsNextLine.hasNextInt()) {
                        int value = scannerWordsNextLine.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("integer on the line after line with \"all\" is " + value);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("PROBLEM: no integer on next line with \"all\"");
                    }
                }
            }
            //previous solution - column based
//          Scanner scannerWords = new Scanner(line);
//          for (int iWord = 0; scannerWords.hasNext(); ++iWord) {
//              String word = scannerWords.next();
//              if ("all".equals(word)) {
//                  System.out.println("found \"all\" one line index " + iLine + " and column index " + iWord);
//                  if (!scannerLines.hasNextLine()) {
//                      System.out.println("PROBLEM: no next line");
//                  } else {
//                      String nextLine = scannerLines.nextLine();
//                      Scanner scannerWordsNextLine = new Scanner(nextLine);
//                      int iWordNextLine = 0;
//                      String wordNextLine = null;
//                      for (; iWordNextLine <= iWord && scannerWordsNextLine.hasNext(); ++iWordNextLine) {
//                          wordNextLine = scannerWordsNextLine.next();
//                      }
//                      if (iWordNextLine != iWord + 1) {
//                          System.out.println("PROBLEM: not enough columns on next line");
//                      } else {
//                          System.out.println("Word on next line = " + wordNextLine);
//                          int integerNextLine = Integer.parseInt(wordNextLine);
//                          //TODO use integerNextLine
//                      }
//                  }
//              }
        }
    }
}
```

My point is, you can use scanner to break into words, not just lines. Of course, there are many ways to solve this. I edited example - it searches for first integer on next line, not for integer on the same position.

Comment: No it school exercise I need that to refill the parsed timetable. Also  the problem is the number (in this case 30 but it could be any other integer number) when I put it at different position in the next line I am getting an error also in the parsed files the number is located at different position of the next line.  Is there an easy way to fix it in your answer code?

Comment: You would have to add that lines as (more) example to the question otherwise I can not help. From your example lines it seems it's column-based and the code worked for your example lines.

Comment: I have changed the simple to unserstand what I mean no it is nocolumn-based it could be at any position.

Comment: @tree I edited the answer, it works now with any position, as requested.