# Get the integer number in the next line of the text document

Tags: java

I am trying to get the number  `30`  in the next line after finding the the string `all` . 
The number in the next line has the following form **space+integer+space**.

It does not have particular index in the line(also the position of the number in the next line  is  different) it is not column-based.

How can I get the number `30` in the next line in this case and store it in int variable?

I appreciate any help.

**Simple**

```
table 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 alle 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
spoon 05:11 05:41 06:14 06:44 07:14 30 07:44 08:14 17:14 17:44 18:14 18:44 19:14 19:44
cabel 05:13 05:43 06:17 06:47 07:17 07:47 08:17 17:17 17:47 Min 18:17 18:47 19:17 19:47
water 05:16 05:46 06:21 06:51 07:21 07:51 08:21 17:21 17:51 18:21 18:51 19:21 19:51
laptop 05:19 05:49 06:25 06:55 07:25 07:55 08:25 17:25 17:55 18:25 18:55 19:25 19:55
tree 05:20 05:50 06:26 06:56 07:26 07:56 08:26 17:26 17:56 18:26 18:56 19:26 19:56
```

**Code:**

```
    Scanner scannerLines = new Scanner(file)) {
    int lineNum = 0;

    while (scannerLines.hasNextLine()) {

        String line = scannerLines.nextLine();

        if (line.contains(" alle ")) {

            scannerLines.nextLine();
            Scanner scannerWords = new Scanner(line);

            while (scannerWords.hasNext()) {

                String words = scannerWords.nextLine();

            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Is it not the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671394/read-exactly-a-string-in-the-next-line-after-maching-the-condition). Why did you ask again???

Comment: @AbishekManoharan: you shoud vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: It is not duplicat the Problem is different there it is column-based but here it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression and get the group that contains the integer.
The final grouping would look something like (\s\d\d\s).

Comment: Note that "\d\d" will only work with 2 digit numbers. I would change "\d\d" to "\d*" to work with numbers of any digit length. Also, \s matches any whitespace, including carriage returns, tab, line feeds, etc.

Comment: How can I use this in Java code?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you already have the line after the one containing " alle " and that it is correctly in the variable `String s` (or call it whatever you want).

I would simply do the following (for instance in a method returning the value):

```
String ss[] = s.split(" ");
for(String x:ss) {
  if(!x.contains(':')) return Integer.valueOf(x);
}
throw new IllegalStateException("Value not found!");
```

It is untested and I'll leave the error handling to you.

Comment: I am jumping to the next line with`scannerlines.nextLine()` but it does not seems to work.... Currently I am getting this error when I try to use your code like this `    if (line.contains(" alle ")) {
     String s = scannerLines.nextLine();
     String ss[] = s.split(' ');` error `The method split(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char)`